# DSE VM from Datastax Cassandra-Spark tutorial gets 'dead kernel' error in Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

When I enter Jupyter notebook from DataStax Spark tutorial; there's a recurring red error status button:  'dead kernel'.  So, I'm not able to run the notebook.

- I tried hitting the button and select 'restart kernel'; but later get that same error immediately after kernel appears to restart itself.
- I also tried opening a terminal window within the VirtualBox to be able to start a spark shell from the command-line; but no /bin directory exists for me to be able to be able to run './bin/spark-shell'.

  > pwd
  >   /root
  >   ls
  >   /spark-kernel 
  >   /jupyter
  >   ...

(/bin is MISSING)

I'm trying this DataStax tutorial here:
https://academy.datastax.com/courses/getting-started-apache-spark

I seemed to be able to install and startup the VM on my VirtualBox OK; as the VM comes up for me; along with Jupyter Notebook.

I'm on a Mac running OSX El Capitain v10.11.4 (15E65); and Virtual Box Version 5.0.16 r105871.

Somehow my VM maybe corrupt?  I had downloaded the ds320-vm-dsa.zip at 2363833330 bytes. I had Added that VM to VirtualBox via a dbl-clk on the *.vbox file after *.zip expansion.  I have Version 5.0.16 r105871 of VirtualBox installed on Mac OSx El Capitan.

Comment: I also tried running 'dse spark' in a terminal window on the VM; but I get this error:  Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to open thrift connection to Cassandra.  So, I looked at this support page and tried the suggestions, but then ran into a different error:  https://academy.datastax.com/content/virtual-box-dse-spark#comment-778

Comment: This DSE version isn't super-awesome.  May just take another route and install software dependencies directly on my local Mac, even though I won't have access to datasets within the tutorial VM, necessarily.

Comment: Also was able to download and install VirtualBox VM for DataStax Sandbox 2.1_1.  VM comes up; but I don't know if it's got the analytics demos setup on it!

Comment: Also tried downloading this:

Comment: I just tried downloading and installing this:  https://oscon2016-friends-with-cassandra.s3.amazonaws.com/oscon2016.2.zip.  VM comes up OK.  However, when I try to enter a spark shell with 'dse spark'; dse isn't recognized; even with 'which dse'.  And, password for 'Demo' isn't 'datastax' apparently.

Comment: LMFAO password for user 'Demo' is 'demo'.  No idea where dse is installed, as its not under ~ directory for demo user!  In any case; non-VM local machine DSE installation works for me now (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to Google this up; which maybe my best bet:
https://github.com/victorcouste/zeppelin-spark-cassandra-demo

THANK YOU Victor Couste!  You're awesome!

The direct DSE non-VM install actually contains the DataStax tutorials under a demo directory.  This is exactly the installed environment I was looking for!